# Apply specific style based on the value in span

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

ListLabel is the span class. The value inside the span can be either a number or any special character. I want to add a period if the value is number.

```html
<span class="ListLabel"> 1 </span> <br>
<span class="ListLabel"> @ </span>
```

Expected O/P 
1. (Period after the number)
@  (Nothing since it's a special character)

Answer (score 1):

something like:

```
function ChangeStuff(){
  var frogs;
  frogs = getElementsByClassName("ListLabel");
  for(var i = 0; i < frogs.length; i++){
    if(Number.isInteger(frogs[i].innerHTML)){
      frogs[i].innerHTML = frogs[i].innerHTML + ".";
    }
  }
}
```

will do what you ask I think.